# Determine if CheckBox in each row of table is selected in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am currently working on a PHP project. I am reading in rows from a MySQL Database and populating them into an HTML table.

What I want to be able to do is to provide a checkbox on each row that the user can select. When they press a submit button it will check to see which checkboxes are clicked and remove them from the database.

How can I determine what checkboxes are clicked when the submit is pressed.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is this a group of checkboxes (e.g. multiple options) or individual checkboxes (e.g. option1, option2)?

Comment: Its individual checkboxes. One checkbox for each row, just selected or not selected so the user can choose what row to delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend loading the IDs into an array. It will make your PHP logic much easier and neater on the backend. Here is a very basic example.

**HTML**

```
<form action="..." method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteId[]" value="1" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteId[]" value="2" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="deleteId[]" value="3" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// If IDs were selected then delete from the database
if( isset($_POST['deleteId']) && count($_POST['deleteId']) >  0 )
{
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $_POST['deleteId']).')';
    mysql_query($sql);
}
else
{
    // no ids were selected
    // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: You should at least mention that you should never insert user submitted data directly into SQL statements before escaping them as it's vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)

Comment: Glad I could help.  As @webbiedave mentioned you should never run a query using raw user input. It can expose your system to some nasty vulnerabilities.  My example was intended to give you a starting framework. Please make sure to validate your input as necessary.  At the very least this would include ensuring that all of the deleteIds are numeric.  Though other validations may apply depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fieldname" value="somevalue" />
```

will submit to the server as

```
fieldname=somevalue
```

if the checkbox was checked. If it's not checked, nothing is submitted at all.

By assigning relevant fieldnames to the checkboxes, and populating their values with the DB record identifiers, you'll be able to see exactly which checkboxes are checked and do the delete operations on the corresponding records.

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden field for each checkbox which can store value 0 or 1.
When you select checkbox you should change value for this field using javascript.
The similar approach uses by zend(I mean hidden fields). This approach helps you to solve problem with checkboxes which are not checked.